# Is this page of Goodfellow's Deep Learning Textbook missing text?

Tags: deep-learning

The textbook Deep Learning by Goodfellow, Bengio, and Courville can be viewed in individual html chapters [here](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/).

I'm currently reading Chapter 15 on Representation Learning and saw this for algorithm 15.1 on page 530:

[image: Page 530]

There no condition after `end for` and similarly no end condition for `end if`. Is that intentional? If so, what is the correct way to interpret it? I haven't encountered algorithm syntax like this in the past.

Answer (score 3):

There is no industry standard for psuedocode as it is read by humans (for the moment ;) and the author can decide how best to represent the concepts of the algorithm with the aim of balancing precision and understandability. In this case there is a

```
FOR ... END FOR
```

block which is iterated over k for 1 to m. And an

```
IF ... END IF
```

block that is run if fine-tuning evaluates to true.